# Ubuntu 18.04 Server not using proxy settings defined in /etc/environment

Tags: server, 18.04, proxy

I've defined the following proxy settings in /etc/environment

```
http_proxy="http://172.30.210.5:3128/"
telnet_proxy="http://172.30.210.5:3128/"
https_proxy="http://172.30.210.5:3128/"
HTTP_PROXY="http://172.30.210.5:3128/"
HTTPS_PROXY="http://172.30.210.5:3128/"
TELNET_PROXY="http://172.30.210.5:3128/"
```

But if I try to telnet to a source allowed I can see that the request is not getting to the Proxy server (logs on Proxy Server and Firewall). I know the server has access to the Proxy as I've also configured the proxy to be used by apt by creating the file /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/95proxies with

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://172.30.210.5:3128/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://172.30.210.5:3128/";
Acquire::https::proxy "http://172.30.210.5:3128/";
```

I can successfully install applications on the server with access via the Proxy. I've also configured the proxy for git and I can clone/push/pull from a repo, but again cannot telnet to hit github.com port 80

I've rebooted the machine also.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you sure the telnet client knows about a `TELNET_PROXY` environment variable? I'm not sure it's as simple as that - see for example [How to telnet via proxy authentication?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36627/how-to-telnet-via-proxy-authentication)